# How do I confine the output of a fetchall() on my table to just the value?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, python-3.6

I have the following function:

```
def credential_check(username, password):
            conn = sqlite3.connect('pythontkinter.db')
            c = conn.cursor()
            idvalue = c.execute('''SELECT ID FROM userdetails WHERE username = "{0}"'''.format(username)).fetchall()
            print(idvalue)
```

I wish to assign the value of ID in my userdetails table to the variable `idvalue` in the row where the inputted username = userdetails username, however when I use this fetchall() I get `[('0',)]` printed out rather than just `0`.

How do I go about doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fetchone()` if you only want one value. However, the result will still be returned as a tuple, just without the list.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testing(id TEXT)''')
conn.commit()

c.execute("""INSERT INTO testing (id) VALUES ('0')""")
conn.commit()

c.execute("""SELECT id FROM testing""")
data = c.fetchone()
print data
# --> (u'0',)
```

You can also use [`LIMIT`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_limit_clause.htm) if you want to restrict the number of returned values with `fetchall()`.

More importantly, don't format your queries like that. Get used to using the `?` placeholder as a habit so that you are not vulnerable to SQL injection.

`idvalue = c.execute("""SELECT ID FROM userdetails WHERE username = ?""", (username,)).fetchone()`